# To call class only once in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

I have laravel application and I have used singleton pattern

```
public function boot/register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            'className',
            new \App\Services\Api\Helpers\className
        );
    }
```

I want to call it once only when first time application bootstrap. It will store value and next time if I make api call, i don't want to call it

But with even singleton, it is calling everytime.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you resolve this binding from the container and you get a different instance every time?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#the-register-method

Comment: @lagbox I am not saying different instance. but I want to call that class only one throughout the application.

Comment: the lifecycle for the application is only the request/response cycle. so as long as you are resolving that binding from the container you should get your singleton ... and as mentioned perhaps the `register` method would be more appropriate ... and do you want the singleton or to bind an instance to the container?

Comment: did you check this tutorial about the implementation of singleton in laravel: 
http://snags88.github.io/singleton-pattern-in-laravel

Comment: @MustafaPoya I have checked this but how this fix the issue of one time call of class when application bootstrap?

Comment: it will prevent from everytime reinitialization.

Comment: @MustafaPoya means  will it not execute code inside that class once it is executed?

Comment: @lagbox i want to call that class once only and register method is calling that class in each api call

Comment: @lagbox  can this be useful? https://github.com/spatie/once

Comment: @MustafaPoya can this be useful? https://github.com/spatie/once

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by call that class only once?

Answer (score 0):

Had to add answer as not got 50 rep yet, but..

Bhumi, the point of a singleton is not that it is only called once, it is that it is only constructed once and stored (Laravel singleton binding or older static variable method), much like putting something in cache.

If you want it to 'live' and be accessed, then it has to be stored, which if using the singleton binding it is.

Even if you used the older method of a static variable storing the instance, you still need a method to get the instance to retrieve the 'stored' instance, the Laravel container is just making things more convenient by handling the storage for you.

This explains more https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe#singletons